# Backing up Jenkins FreeStyle jobs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Jenkins pipelines are stored in repo and we will use them in Jenkins.
Is there a way to save freestyle jobs in the repo in automated way.

Comment: Is your intent just to have a backup checked in, or do you intend to use the repo as the job source of truth (ie:read only Jenkins UI)?

Comment: Job Source of truth.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way to store the definition of a Free-Style job in a file format, which can be imported like a Jenkinsfile.